# Google Map GMSCircle

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I am using Google map API in my project. I added `GMSCircle` as an overlay.

I want to delete all the added circles.There is no method to remove "`GMSCircle`" from '`mapview`'.

How can I remove circle from `mapview`?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a private property that will hold the GMSCircle instances.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *circlesOnMap;
```

Lazy load it.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)circlesOnMap {
    if (!_circlesOnMap) {
        _circlesOnMap = [NSMutableArray array];
        return _circlesOnMap;
    }
    return _circlesOnMap;
}
```

Whenever I add my circle to the map, I also add it to my property

```
...
googleCircle.map = self.mapView;
[self.circlesOnMap addObject:googleCircle];
...
```

If I need to remove any circles on the map, I iterate through my property

```
if (self.circlesOnMap.count > 0) {
    [self.circlesOnMap enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        GMSCircle *aCircle = (GMSCircle *)obj;
        aCircle.map = nil;
    }];
}
```

This removes all the circles on the map, you can modify it based on what you want to do.